# Ajax ,css and JS file not loading in subdomain

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have an asp.net website with sub-domain.  If users brows sub.domain.com, I am redirecting it to a folder called sub-domain using iis rule written in web.config file.  But my problem is css and js files are not loading in that landing page.

My IIS redirection rule is as follows:

```
<rule name="sub" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub.domain.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/sub-domain/Default.aspx" />
</rule>
```

**My main Problem ajax is not loading**
in the view source am getting this following error.
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Use relative paths for your css and javascript files, that should do the work.